# Neo4j/Cypher optionally create a Node and relationship based on whether a JSON object is empty or not

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, apollo, grandstack

First off, I am using the GRANDstack with Flutter as my frontend. Not super relevant, but for context. I have a CreatePost mutation:

```
mutation CreatePost(\$body: String!, \$userId: ID!, \$imageReference: CreateImageReference!, \$mentions: [String!]) {
  CreatePost(body: \$body, userId: \$userId, imageReference: \$imageReference, mentions: \$mentions) {
    id,
    body,
    createdAt {
      formatted
    },
    updatedAt {
      formatted
    },
    user {
      username
    },
    imageReference {
      downloadURL
    }
  }
}
```

that is successfully sending my `CreateImageReference` input as JSON with `name` and `downloadURL` attributes. The custom input type:

```
input CreateImageReference {
    name: String!
    downloadURL: String!
}
```

in my schema file is straightforward and being accepted by apollo/graphql just fine. I am logging the "graphqlResponse" to monitor everything and there appears to be no issue up to this point.

I am attempting to "optionally create" this `ImageReference` node and a relationship to the `Post` node based on whether the `$imageReference` parameter is null or not. My custom mutation with cypher query without the addition of the `ImageReference` logic:

```
CreatePost(body: String!, userId: ID!, imageReference: CreateImageReference!, mentions: [String!]): Post
    @cypher(
      statement: """
        MATCH (u:User {id: $userId})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
        OPTIONAL MATCH (g)-[rel:NEWEST_POST]->(prevNewest:Post)
        CREATE (u)-[:WROTE]->(p:Post {id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: $body, createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime()})<-[:NEWEST_POST]-(g)
        MERGE (u)-[hp:HAS_PARTICIPATED]->(g)
        ON MATCH SET hp.updatedAt = p.createdAt
        ON CREATE SET hp.createdAt = p.createdAt, hp.updatedAt = p.createdAt
        FOREACH(i in CASE WHEN NOT rel IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
        DELETE rel CREATE (p)-[:NEXT_POST]->(prevNewest))
        WITH p
        OPTIONAL MATCH (allMentionedUsers:User)
        WHERE allMentionedUsers.id in $mentions
        UNWIND allMentionedUsers as mentionedUser
        MERGE (p)-[:MENTIONS]->(mentionedUser)
        // Add CREATE ImageReference and
        // Add CREATE relationship (HAS_ATTACHMENT) between ImageReference and Post here
        RETURN p
    """)
```

What is the most efficient way to check if the variable $imageReference `IS NULL` and do nothing if it is vs. run the CREATE node/relationship statements when `NOT IS NULL`:

```
CREATE (i:ImageReference {id: apoc.create.uuid(), name: $imageReference['name'], downloadURL: $imageReference['downloadURL']}
WITH i
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_ATTACHMENT]-(i)
```

Here is an attempt with CASE:

```
CASE $imageReference
WHEN null []
ELSE CREATE (i:ImageReference {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(), 
    name: $imageReference['name'], 
    downloadURL: $imageReference['downloadURL'],
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime(),
    deletedAt: null
})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_ATTACHMENT]->(i)
WITH i END
```

that is throwing a `"Neo4jError: Failed to invoke procedure` apoc.cypher.doIt`: Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 10, column 3 (offset: 678))",`.

Here is an attempt with FOREACH that is successfully creating the Post, but not the ImageReference with no errors to indicate why:

```
FOREACH (i in CASE WHEN NOT $imageReference IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    CREATE (ir:ImageReference {
        id: apoc.create.uuid(), 
        name: $imageReference['name'], 
        downloadURL: $imageReference['downloadURL'],
        createdAt: datetime(),
        updatedAt: datetime(),
        deletedAt: null
    })
    CREATE (p)-[:HAS_ATTACHMENT]->(ir))
```

If I execute this part:

```
CREATE (ir:ImageReference {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(), 
    name: $imageReference['name'], 
    downloadURL: $imageReference['downloadURL'],
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime(),
    deletedAt: null
})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_ATTACHMENT]->(ir))
```

without the CASE or FOREACH, it successfully creates the Node and relationship as expected, which is fine until I want to create a post without an ImageReference. Perhaps the solution is to just create two different queries?

Comment: Take a look at: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/conditional-cypher-execution/

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying with a FOREACH, which is successfully creating the Post, but not the ImageReference (with no errors as to why). I added it to the question if you have a chance to take a peak. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.when/) to perform if-then-else processing that can write to the DB ([apoc.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc/apoc.when/) can be used for read-only processing).

For example, your last snippet can be done this way:

```
...
CALL apoc.do.when(
  $imageReference IS NOT NULL,
  ' CREATE (ir:ImageReference {
      id: apoc.create.uuid(), 
      name: ref.name, 
      downloadURL: ref.downloadURL,
      createdAt: datetime(),
      updatedAt: datetime()
    })
    CREATE (p)-[:HAS_ATTACHMENT]->(ir)
    RETURN ir',
  '',
  {ref: $imageReference, p: p}
) YIELD value
WITH p, value.ir AS ir
...
```